# search and export the data in .csv format using django

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, django-admin

In my application i am using a search function which search and display the output.I include search for `fromdate and todate`,`Keyword search` etc.

I want to export the searched result in a `.csv` file.Currently i had written a function called `csv_export` and exporting all the report in .csv.I want to know how to export the searched item in a .csv file.

forms.py for search

```
class SearchFilterForm(Form):
    location = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices='',required=False)
    type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices='',required=False)
    fromdate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy','class':'datefield','readonly':'readonly'}))
    todate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy','class':'datefield','readonly':'readonly'})) 
    search_keyword = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Keyword Search','class':'keyword-search'}))
```

views.py for search

```
def search(request):
    """Search reports using filters
    """
    user = request.user
    report_list = []
    searchfilter = SearchFilterForm(user) 
    reports = Report.objects.filter(user=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       if 'search' in request.POST:
            search_keyword = request.POST.get('search_keyword') #reports filter by keywords
            reports = reports.filter(Q(incident_description__icontains=search_keyword)|Q(incident_number__icontains=search_keyword))
        elif 'filter' in request.POST:
            searchfilter = SearchFilterForm(user,request.POST)
            loc_id = request.POST.get('location')
            type_id = request.POST.get('type')
            start_date = request.POST.get('fromdate')
            end_date = request.POST.get('todate')
            reportlist = []
            """"""""""" #some stuff for search come here
            if start_date or end_date:                 
                if start_date and not end_date:
                    reports = reports.filter(created_date_time__gte=start_date)
                elif not start_date and end_date:
                    reports = reports.filter(created_date_time__lte=end_date)
                elif start_date and end_date:
                    reports = reports.filter(created_date_time__gt=start_date,created_date_time__lt=end_date)
    for report in reports:
      """"""  report iteration goes here
        report_list.append(items)
    return render(request, 'incident/search.html',
                   {'SearchKeywordForm':searchform,})
```

Apart from search button a button called `save-spreadsheet` is their on the same search page,on clicking search button the searched items are come to display and while clicking `save-spreadsheet` button the displayed items are exported to `.csv` file.

Need help to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the [django documentation about outputting CSV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/).

You can display a list of search results like:

```
<ul>
    <li><form method="GET" action="/reports/1/csv/"><input type="submit" value="Get Report 1 csv" /></form></li>
    <li><form method="GET" action="/reports/30/csv/"><input type="submit" value="Get Report 30 csv" /></from></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

And create a view that outputs a CSV for given report id:

urls.py

```
url(r'^reports/(?P<report_id>\d+)/csv/$', 'reports.views.csv_report')
```

views.py

```
def csv_report(request, report_id):
    report = Reports.objects.get(pk=report_id)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.csv"'
    response.write(report.to_csv())  # TODO to_csv
    return response
```

Comment: Erviala,exporting to .csv is not my actual problem,that i learned from same docs,my requirement is,i want to export the searched reported alone into .csv format and not all report.As i had already writen a csv export function and it is exporting the whole report.I want to export the searched report alone into .csv format.Please guide me.

Comment: Erviala,using django i had written a search functionality,which display the searched output.I am having the following search option 1.Keyword search,2.using date'etc.For example,totally 100 records are their in database and while using keyword search will display result related to that keyword,i want to export that searched data into .csv.Simply,i want to export the data into .csv format depends on search scenario.

Comment: @user2086641 is this your problem? 1. Get results from search | 2. Show results to user | 3. User wants a CSV of one result. | 4. how to give CSV from results page?